# Embedded reference not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, reference, mongoid

Under mongoid and rails 3 I have a collection of **Users** and a collection a **Projects** which embed many **Relationships**, the models are:

> class User 
> include Mongoid::Document 
> field :name, :type => String 
> referenced_in :relationship, :inverse_of => :user 
> end
>
> class Project 
> include Mongoid::Document
> field :title, :type => String
> embeds_many :relationships
> end
>
> class Relationship
> include Mongoid::Document
> field :type, :type => String
> references_one :user
> embedded_in :subject, :inverse_of => :relationships
> end

My problem is that the referenced user of a relationship is never saved into the relationship. For example for following command only saves **:type**:

> project1 = Project.new( :title => "project1", :relationships => [ {:type => "master", :user => "4d779568bcd7ac0899000002"} ] )

My goal is to have a project document similar to this:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4d77a8b2bcd7ac08da00000f"), "title" : "project1", "relationships" : [
> {
> "type" : "master",
> "user" : ObjectId("4d775effbcd7ac05a8000002"),
> "_id" : ObjectId("4d77a8b2bcd7ac08da000010")
> }
> ] }

The **:user** is never present, am I missing something here? Thanks a lot for your help!

Ted

Comment: Which version of mongoid do you use?

Comment: I have this problem with mongoid 2.0.0

Comment: Probably you have solved it by now, but try removing `referenced_in :relationship` from user and change `references_one :user` in relationship to `referenced_in :user`

Answer (score 1):

So a couple things you might want to change:

1) Avoid the field name "type" as this is a rails magic column name used by single table inheritance. Maybe change them to user_type and relationship_type.

2) With Mongoid 2.0 and up you can use Active Model syntax like has_many and belongs_to instead of references. http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-n.html

3) For your create, instead of assigning *user* with a user ID, try assigning a user object.

```
project1 = Project.new( :title => "project1", :relationships => [ {:type => "master", :user => User.first} ] )
```

Or you could assign a user_id like so:

```
project1 = Project.new( :title => "project1", :relationships => [ {:type => "master", :user_id => "the_use_id_you_want_to_associate"} ] )
```

FYI, you don't have to specify the inverse_of in "referenced_in :relationship, :inverse_of => :user". Just "referenced_in :relationship" will do the trick.